# Ajax Submit Form not work Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

А Hello everyone, I'm having a problem with the following code is not executed correctly and completely in Firefox, as it should appear on a  something (charging, check errors) from the server  after clicking on submit, but Firefox does not, just do a normal submit, as if there were no Ajax...

Can you help me?

In advance thank you very much!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_form").click(function() {
    $("#source_form").submit(function(e) {
      $("#response_form").html("<div class='alert alert-info'><b><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Un momento...</b></div>");
      var postData_form = $(this).serializeArray();
      var formURL_form = $(this).attr("action");
      $.ajax({
        url: formURL_form,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData_form,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $("#response_form").html('' + data + '');
          $('#submit_form').prop("disabled", false);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $("#response_form").html('Error: <br/> ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + '');
          $('#submit_form').prop("disabled", false);
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#source_form").unbind();
      $('#submit_form').prop("disabled", true);
    });
    $("#source_form").submit();
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="source_form" action="check_login.php">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Email">Usuario o Email</label>
<input type="text" name="Usuario" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Usuario o Email" title="Ingresa tu usuario o email" required value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Password">Contrase&ntilde;a <a href="#" onclick="url_target('/inc/recupera.password.php?frame=1');">(Recuperar contrase&ntilde;a)</a></label>
<input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" title="Ingresa tu password asignado" required value="">
</div>
<div id="response_form" align="center"></div>
<div id="submit_div"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_form">Conectarse</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Do any errors appear in the browser's console? Why are you binding the submit handler *inside* the click handler? And what is the `getDoc()` function for? It's not called anywhere in the code shown.

Comment: You need to stop the propagation before the ajax request

Comment: If it works in other browsers, but Firefox

I just supplement the code where I have the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need a `submit` handler in a `click` handler. All you need is just a `submit` handler as the button with type `submit` would anyway trigger the `submit` handler. Another advantage of using the `submit` handler is that one can submit the form even using the enter key! I have removed the `click` handler, slightly modified your ajax to make it a bit more cleaner. Take a look and modify the code to suit your needs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#source_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit_form').prop("disabled", true);
        $("#response_form").html("<div class='alert alert-info'><b><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Un momento...</b></div>");
        var postData_form = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL_form = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            url: formURL_form,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData_form
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#response_form").html(data);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#response_form").html('Error: ' + jqXHR. statusText);
        }).always(function() {
            $('#submit_form').prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });
});
```

The above worked for me in FF, Chrome, Safari etc.

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwvve46e/) that uses the ajax simulator URL from within jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an in-depth response, but, per the Ajax documentation, the '$' sign is a shortcut to writing 'jQuery'. 
It may be worthwhile to change the '$' sign before '.ajax' as FireFox or Edge may interpret the '$' sign as a variable or function.
Therefore,
'$.ajax({... }}'
becomes
'jQuery.ajax({...})'.
It does not hurt to try. I would also recommend viewing the FireFox console to view the JavaScript errors that are thrown as well.